# Организация ЧПУ на сайте

Tags: .htaccess, php

У меня следующий вопрос:

дан адрес страницы, допустим **lol.ru/people.php**

хотелось бы видеть такой адрес **lol.ru/people**

Думаю, общий смысл понятен. Как это организовать?

Answer (score 3):

Создайте в корне файл .htaccess

В нем:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ router.php?file=$1 [L]
```

router.php

```
<?
$file = !empty($_GET['file']) ? str_replace('/', '', $_GET['file']) : false;
if (!!$file && file_exists($fn = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$file.'.php')) { require $fn; exit; } // еcли файл есть, включаем его
header('Location: /'); // иначе шлем на главную.
exit;
?>
```

А вообще это вполне можно было за 10 мин узнать в гугле.